# static web site authoring and modularity

Tags: html, web

I have been working creating a new project static web site and was wondering what's the correct way to reuse the header, footer etc into a HTML base that can be "imported" and reused in all pages. Currently I replicate all the code and this is not really a good thing. Using JQuery and dynamic divs for this simple use-case is an overkill I believe.

The website I have been working on is this:
http://hpsfo.bitbucket.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try server side include (SSI).
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html